# agavi set cookie

Tags: php, agavi

I don't know anything about agavi and there might be a lot of error in this..

I want to set up a cookie:

```
$this->getResponse()->setCookie( ID, 'ID=2342&amp;ClickBannerID=634&amp;SubID=&amp;ClickDateTime=' + time(), mixed $lifetime = time() * 2, string $path = '/', string $domain = 'mydomain', bool $secure = null)
```

I get:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

it's form: http://www.agavi.org/apidocs/index.html
what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

Usually within Agavi you set cookies on an *AgaviView* on the *AgaviWebResponse* object via its *setCookie* method. The method signature is as follows:

```
public function setCookie($name, $value, $lifetime = null, $path = null, $domain = null, $secure = null, $httponly = null)
```

This means, that you can set a simple cookie using the following syntax:

```
$this->getResponse()->setCookie('cookieName', $cookieValue);
```

You may use [PHP's strtotime function](http://php.net/strtotime) to set an easily readable lifetime for the cookie if you want a cookie that is only valid for a certain amount of time:

```
$this->getResponse()->setCookie('cookieName', $cookieValue, '+14 days');
```

As your question states you may want to use the additional parameters (domain etc.) as well. Reading your question it may also be possible, that you want to set multiple cookies instead of one consisting of a string containing *ID*, *ClickBannerId* etc., but only you and your application (or your dev) can tell that.

Please note, that you can set the additional parameters per cookie or configure some sane defaults for your application in the *app/config/factories.xml* file per *environment* (usually for *context* _web_) to save on typing in your views:

```
<response class="AgaviWebResponse">
    <ae:parameters name="cookie_httponly">true</ae:parameters>
</response>
```

The valid parameter names are:

- cookie_lifetime (lifetime in seconds)
- cookie_path (path on the server the cookie should be available for)
- cookie_domain (the domain the cookie is available on)
- cookie_secure (set this to *true* if the cookie should only be available via HTTPS)
- cookie_httponly (determine whether the cookie should only be allowed to use via HTTP and not client side scripts)

Please note, that the *ae* namespace was not necessary in older Agavi versions and thus it may be needed that you use *parameter* instead of *ae:parameter*.

To remove a cookie you just call *unsetCookie* with all the same parameters you used for setting the cookie. To get a cookie value simply call *getCookie($name)*. As cookies are untrusted user provided information usually Agavi requires you to validate all incoming parameters, files, headers and cookies before you can access them in your *actions* and *views*. This means, that you may need to validate your cookie prior to accessing its value. You do this via a *validate.xml* file:

```
<validator class="string" source="cookie" required="false">
    <argument>cookieName</argument>
</validator>
```

This example is simplified and should not be used in production. Use *source* _cookie_ and the name of the cookie for the *argument* and then validate your cookie value according to your rules (format etc.). It may be necessary to write a custom validator if the builtin *AgaviValidator* classes (like string, regex etc.) are not sufficient, but this is a topic for another day. You may find the [Agavi User FAQ](http://mivesto.de/agavi/agavi-faq.html) somewhat helpful. Sorry for the shameless plug and good luck with your problem at hand. :-)

Answer (score 0):

you mixed function declaration with its run

```
$this->getResponse()->setCookie( 'your-cookie-id','ID=2342&ClickBannerID=634&SubID=&ClickDateTime=' . time(),  time() * 2,  '/',  
'mydomain', null)
```

and as OcuS stated in comment - probably hire a PHP developer

Comment: Thanks Jerzy, now I'm getting: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in that line..

and my PHP developer is on vacation for the next 2 weeks so i thought I will ask for help with 1 line..

Comment: add ; at the end of this line